# Jenkins - how do I set multiple parameters with one choice

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins.
I need to run a parameterized job, where a single selection determines several parameters. For example, if I choose "A" then the product name is "HitMe", the bundle identifier is "com.foo.bar" and the code signing certificate is "/Users/Shared/cert1.pfx".

Thus, when I select A from the select box, I can later use ${PRODUCT_NAME} and ${BUNDLE_ID} and other parameters, all set because I chose A.

Ideally I'd like to place this mapping in a single text file (example in javascript just for clarity):

```
{
A: { PRODUCT_NAME: "HitMe", BUNDLE_ID: "com.foo.bar", certificate: "/Users/Shared/cert1.pfx" },
B: { PRODUCT_NAME: "Rub", BUNDLE_ID: "com.baz.bla", certificate: "/Users/Shared/cert2.pfx" }
}
```

Then read this text file and base the choice on its content. However, inline will also work for now. I've read tons of pages about the extended choice plugins but nothing clicked (for me). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Active Choices plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) is your friend here.  In particular Reactive Reference parameters.

Due to [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43663), you can download the plugin [here](https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/biouno/uno-choice/1.5.3/uno-choice-1.5.3.hpi).